# luaotfload | load : path lookup unsuccessful

Tags: fonts, luatex, opentype, luaotfload

When I typeset documents with `LuaLaTeX` and OpenType fonts I regularly get messages like this in the `.log` file

```
 luaotfload | load : path lookup of "Palatino Linotype.ttf" unsuccessful,      
 falling back to file:(compiling luc: /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/palatino-linotype.luc)(compiling luc:      
 /Users/simi/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/palatino-linotype.luc)(save: 
 /Users/simi/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/palatino-linotype.lua)(save: 
 /Users/simi/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/palatino-linotype.luc)
 luaotfload | load : path lookup of "Palatino Linotype.ttf" unsuccessful, falling back to file: \g__fontspec_family_PalatinoLinotype_int=\count161
 luaotfload | load : path lookup of "PalatinoLinotype.ttf" unsuccessful, falling back to file:(compiling luc: /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/palatinolinotype.luc)(compiling luc: 
 /Users/simi/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/palatinolinotype.luc)(save: /Users/simi/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/palatinolinotype.lua)(save: /Users/simi/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/palatinolinotype.luc)
 luaotfload | load : path lookup of "PalatinoLinotype.ttf" unsuccessful, falling back to file:
```

There are several strange things about this:

- `LuaLaTeX` does actually compile the document with the defined font. Typesetting doesn't fail (which it normally does if `fontspec` fails to find a font).
- `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/palatino-linotype.luc` which is given as first fallback, doesn't exist.
- `/Users/simi/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/palatino-linotype.luc` does exist, but it looks like it's recreated every time. At least, when I delete this directory before the `LuaLaTeX` run, it gets recreated.
- In the last part of this error message, simply no path is given, it just says `falling back to file:`

Contrary to errors given, `LuaLaTeX/luaotfload` actually *does* seem to find the needed font file. So what is the meaning of this message then?

Comment: Are you sure the font is found? I have a similar situation, but my font is replaced by another one (at least it looks wrong and in the past it was ok).

Comment: Yes, it is found.

Comment: Is the question still open with the new luatex/luaotfload? If yes could show an example document?

Comment: With all the recent updates to `LuaTeX`, `luoatfload` and `fontspec`, this looks completely different now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP states everything is different with the new version